# ArcGIS Online Attachments sorting

Tags: arcgis-online, sorting, attachments

I'm working with a feature class where I've generated 11 match tables for attachments for 11 chronological and numerically sorted fields.  After going through the attachment process, everything is sorted correctly in the feature class, but when it's published to our ArcGIS Online webmap, it's completely unsorted in the attachment section of the pop-up box.

Is there a reason for this or controls for the pop-up box to sort the attachments numerically?

I've attached screenshots of the same polygon's attachments. The sorted list is off the SDE, the unsorted list is the published pop-up box from our webmap.

[image: Sorted Attachments]

[image: Unsorted Attachments]